fluent-bit different timestamp in logs
I am trying to push my application logs from ec2 machines to Kinesis firehose and from there to Opensearch.
This is one sample log:
127.0.0.1 - - - 2024-05-22T17:16:01.570+0000 "GET /server-status?auto HTTP/1.1" 200 1292 267 108 1465 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1" -

For this :
[INPUT]
    Name   tail
    Path   /var/log/httpd/access_log
    Parser apache_log_parser
    Tag    apache_logs

[FILTER]
    Name modify
    Match apache_logs
    Add host      ABC
[PARSER]
    Name        apache_log_parser
    Format      regex
    Regex       ^(?<client_ip>[^ ]+) - - - (?<timestamp>[^ ]+) "(?<method>[^ ]+) (?<path>[^ ]+) (?<protocol>[^"]+)" (?<code>[^ ]+) (?<size>[^ ]+) (?<duration>[^ ]+) (?<cpu>[^ ]+) (?<mem>[^ ]+) "(?<user_agent>[^"]+)" "(?<referrer>[^"]+)" (?<request_time>[^ ]+)
    Time_Key    timestamp
    Time_Format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L%z
    Time_Keep   On

This works fine and I am able to read it in Opensearch with timestamp.
But when I try to read these logs:
127.0.0.1 - - [23/May/2024:00:47:00 +0000] "GET /metrics/ HTTP/1.1" 200 18130 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1" 2
10.114.30.210 - - [23/May/2024:00:47:07 +0000] "GET /healthcheck HTTP/1.1" 200 159 "-" "Blackbox Exporter/0.25.0" 0

with this configuration:
[INPUT]
    Name   tail
    Path   /abc/logs/access.log
    Parser clf_log_parser
    Tag    access_logs
[FILTER]
    Name modify
    Match access_logs
    Add host      ABC
[PARSER]
    Name   clf_log_parser
    Format regex
    Regex  ^(?<client_ip>[^ ]+) - - \[(?<timestamp>[^\]]+)\] "(?<method>[^ ]+) (?<path>[^ ]+) (?<protocol>[^"]+)" (?<code>[^ ]+) (?<size>[^ ]+) "(?<user_agent>[^"]+)" "(?<referrer>[^"]+)" (?<request_time>[^ ]+)
    Time_Key timestamp
    Time_Format %d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z
    Time_Keep   On

I get these errors in :

Preview of field's value: '23/May/2024:03:46:00
+0000'","caused_by":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"failed
to parse date field [23/May/2024:03:46:00 +0000] with format
[strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis]","caused_by":{"type":"date_time_parse_exception","reason":"date_time_parse_exception:
Failed to parse with

PLease guide
